# Android 6.0 app crash with error on google map null

Tags: android, google-maps

my app run with a swip tab with map fragment and list fragment.
The app workf fine on all device with API from 4.3 to 5.1 but when i run on a Android device with API 6.0 i recive this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
```

this a snippet code of file generate error:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mappa, null, false);

    // To get City-Name from coordinates
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        else {
            //gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        if (cityName == "Rome"){
            nome_citta = "Roma";
        }
        if (cityName == "Florence") {
            nome_citta = "Firenze";
        }
        if (cityName == "Valencia") {
            nome_citta = "Valence";
        }
        nome_citta = cityName;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    /*ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TabFragment()).commit();
        }
    });*/






    GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    GPSService mGPSService = new GPSService(getActivity());
    Double la = mGPSService.getLatitude();
    /*mGPSService.getLocation();
    if (mGPS.canGetLocation()) {
        address = mGPSService.getLocationAddress();
        Log.d("Address","Adrress"+address);
    } else {
        mGPS.showSettingsAlert();
    }*/



    processMap(v,10);

    // map.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());

    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Car2GoClusterItem>(getActivity(), map);

    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<Car2GoClusterItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(Car2GoClusterItem item) {
            clickedClusterItem = item;
            return false;
        }
    });

    //      map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    return v;



}

public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position)
        {
            Log.d("Zoom", "Zoom: " + position.zoom);

            if(previousZoomLevel<=15 && position.zoom>15)
            {
                map.clear();
                processMap(v, 16);
            }

            if(previousZoomLevel>=15 && position.zoom<15)
            {
                map.clear();
                processMap(v, 14);
            }

            previousZoomLevel = position.zoom;
        }
    };
}

public void processMap(View v, int zoom) {
    if(map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }


    if(map != null){
     // othe code here ....................
    }
```

Why i have this error only on Android 6?
How can i fix this issue?
Thanks

If i set

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mappa, null, false);

    // To get City-Name from coordinates
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());

    String cityName = null;
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        else {
            //gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        if (cityName == "Rome"){
            nome_citta = "Roma";
        }
        if (cityName == "Florence") {
            nome_citta = "Firenze";
        }
        if (cityName == "Valencia") {
            nome_citta = "Valence";
        }
        nome_citta = cityName;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    /*ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TabFragment()).commit();
        }
    });*/






    GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    GPSService mGPSService = new GPSService(getActivity());
    Double la = mGPSService.getLatitude();
    /*mGPSService.getLocation();
    if (mGPS.canGetLocation()) {
        address = mGPSService.getLocationAddress();
        Log.d("Address","Adrress"+address);
    } else {
        mGPS.showSettingsAlert();
    }*/



    processMap(v,10);

    // map.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());

    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<Car2GoClusterItem>(getActivity(), map);

    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.getMarkerManager());
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<Car2GoClusterItem>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClusterItemClick(Car2GoClusterItem item) {
            clickedClusterItem = item;
            return false;
        }
    });

    //      map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    return v;



}

public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position)
        {
            Log.d("Zoom", "Zoom: " + position.zoom);

            if(previousZoomLevel<=15 && position.zoom>15)
            {
                map.clear();
                processMap(v, 16);
            }

            if(previousZoomLevel>=15 && position.zoom<15)
            {
                map.clear();
                processMap(v, 14);
            }

            previousZoomLevel = position.zoom;
        }
    };
}

public void processMap(View v, int zoom) {


    if(map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);




    }


    if(map != null){
    }
```

and implement OnMapReadyCallback i have error on this line:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

error getMapAsync return GoogleMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getMap()` is deprecated in Android 6.0, use `getMapAsync()`:

> The previously-deprecated getMap() function is no longer available in
>   the Google Play services SDK. (It is still available in the Google
>   Play services APK that is delivered to Android devices.) The getMap()
>   function has been deprecated since December 2014. See the release blog
>   post for help with converting from getMap() to getMapAsync().

More info here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases

Change this:

```
public void processMap(View v, int zoom) {
    if(map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    }


    if(map != null){
     // othe code here ....................
    }
```

For this:

```
public void processMap(View v, int zoom) {
    if(map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

    }


    if(map != null){
     // othe code here ....................
    }

@Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
     mMap = map;
     doStuff();
 }
```

And Implement `OnMapReadyCallback`

More info here:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/marker-zindex-and-more-come-to-google.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have seen the getMapAsync but i  have a fragment and if i use your change have error on line about getMapAsync and cannot resole doStuff() method

Comment: doStuff() is a mock function, change it for your functionality